# Making POST Requests in Backbone.js

Tags: rest, post, backbone.js, url-encoding

I have a RESTful server, which accepts url encoded parameters.

In my case, making a post request to  https:// my server:8443/test/auth

Set the request header as 
Content-Type : application/x-www-form-urlencoded

and passing the parameters

username=myusername
password=mypassword

works and gives the desired response.

I want to achieve the same using Backbonejs. So, I have

```
        Person = Backbone.Model.extend({
    initialize: function() {
        this.on('all', function(e) { console.log(this.get('name') + " event " + e );
         });

    },

    urlRoot: "https:// my server:8443/test/authauth",
    url : function(){
        var base = this.urlRoot;
        return base + ""
    }
});



 var person = new Person({ "username" : "myusername" , "password":"mypassword" });
 person.save(null, {
    beforeSend: function(xhr) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    }}
 );
```

But, it says that no username and password attributes are not present. Waht is the correct way to pass the paramteres in url encoded form in Backbone.js

Thanks

Comment: Should be a colon between "username" and "myusername". Not sure if that will solve your problem though as unsure how you are parsing the username and password on server side. Do you want them to be sent in headers? Or in the url?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I want the username and password in the body of the request in url_encoded form. e.g. http://grab.by/xyeC , this works